# Microsoft Azure cross tanents access

Tags: azure, stream, multi-tenant

My company has two Microsoft Azure tenants A and B. Currently some video are stored in Microsoft Stream server in tenant A. Is there a way to share those videos to users in tenants B?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not available as of now and not supported, You can see the roadmap [`here`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=stream).